# Como colocar uma imagem como plano de fundo usando a biblioteca "PySimpleGUI"?

Tags: python

O Código que eu tentei utilizar para colocar a imagem , mas não consegui foi esse :

```
 [sg.Image(r"C:\Users\Josiene\Desktop\Criptografia1.png")],
```

E esse é todo o código :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('Dark')  

layout = [
          [sg.Text('Your typed chars appear here:'), sg.Text(size=(12,1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
          [sg.Image(r"C:\Users\Josiene\Desktop\Criptografia1.png")], #Esse é o código que eu coloquei achando que a imagem ia ficar como plano de fundo.
          [sg.Input(key='-IN-')],
          [sg.Button('Show'), sg.Button('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

while True: 
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Show':
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(values['-IN-'])

window.close()
```

- Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- > Estou querendo colocar uma imagem como plano de fundo , mas a imagem quando coloco fica encima do "Input" e dos botões.

Comment: mostra a saída de como está ficando.

Comment: coloquei a saída do código

Comment: Tem que colocar aquela imagem do "cadeado azul" como plano de fundo.Você sabe fazer isso ?

Comment: Não sei, é que colocando a saída as pessoas podem interpretar melhor o que deve ser feito. Vi que usando o Tk() é mais simples mas sobre essa biblioteca que você está utilizando eu não achei nada.

Comment: beleza mano , obrigado por ter tentado, eu acho que algum dia quem criou a biblioteca  venha aqui e responda kkkkkk

Comment: por nada! se eu encontrar alguma solução eu posto aqui

Comment: Achou a solução?

Comment: É preciso colocar a imagem em background,eu não lir a documentação nessa parte,mas esse é o link da doc:
https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#image-element

Answer (score -2):

boa tarde!!

O PySimpleGUI ainda não tem a função Background para a Janela, temos que aguardar a atualização, para interface além daquelas que veem por padrão posso te recomendar a criação do seu próprio tema com o seguinte comando:

sg.SetOptions(background_color='#363636',
text_element_background_color='#363636',
element_background_color='#363636',
scrollbar_color=None,
input_elements_background_color='#F7F3EC',
button_color=('white', '#4F4F4F'))